# LuaLaTex and _output.yml configuration - Error in base format()

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I am learning how to use `bookdown` package and right now I am practicing with Yihui Xie minimal example. In my test I want a gitbook and a pdf output.

What I would like to do is to specifying some options for pdf output with LuaLaTeX engine. So if I do something like that :

```
    bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: lualatex
  fontsize: 12pt
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

I have this error when I try to build the book :

```
Error in base_format(toc = toc, number_sections = number_sections, fig_caption = fig_caption,  : 
  unused argument (fontsize = "12pt")
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution stoped

Exited with status 1.
```

If I put `fontsize: 12pt` in the YAML header of the `index.Rmd`, I don't have this error. If I use `bookdown::pdf_document2:` I don't have this error either.

I really don't know what I am missing here... Should I place LaTeX configuration options only in the YAML header of my `index.Rmd`file ?